# LIBGDX animation does not play or loop

Tags: android, libgdx

I have a coin animation that seems to be right, but it doesn't play or loop, just the first image appears. I also have a class called Moedas(coins), and I would like to use their position to set the animation x and y, but if I do this, it doesn't even appear on the screen. What could be causing this?

```
public Janela2 (MyGdxGame mgg){
   super(mgg);
   TextureAtlas at = new TextureAtlas("Arquivos.txt"); 
   coin1 = new Moedas(texture);
   coin2 = new Moedas(texture);
   TextureAtlas atlas = new TextureAtlas("Arquivos.txt");
   TextureRegion tr1 = new TextureRegion(atlas.findRegion("m321"));
   TextureRegion tr2 = new TextureRegion((atlas.findRegion("m322")));
   TextureRegion tr3 = new TextureRegion(atlas.findRegion("m323"));
   TextureRegion tr4 = new TextureRegion((atlas.findRegion("m324")));
   TextureRegion array[] = {tr1, tr2, tr3, tr4};
   time = 0f;
   ani = new Animation<TextureRegion>(0.5f,array);
   ani.setPlayMode(Animation.PlayMode.LOOP);
}
 public void render(float delta) {
    sp.begin();
    sp.draw(img, 0,0);
    sp.draw(player2, player2.getX(), player2.getY());
    Movimento.movement2(player2, boundingRecPlayer);
        if (Player.saimoeda(boundingRecCoin, boundingRecPlayer)) { 
    //collision method for testing if the player has touched the coin
            sp.draw(img, 0, 0);
            Movimento.movement(player, boundingrecp);
            sp.draw(player2, player2.getX(), player2.getY())
        } else {
            time = Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
            TextureRegion t = ani.getKeyFrame(time, true);
            sp.draw(t, 50, 50);//static x and y because Moedas.x and Moedas.y doesnt work
    }
    sp.end();
}

@Override
public void dispose() {

   super.dispose();

 }
}
```

Comment: Please use better-describing names for your variables. Because nobody expects you will know what `if(!x)` means but if you write `if(!playerTouchCoin)` everyone will see at first glance what this if statement does. Also the name `p2` no one knows what you will draw here. And `a`, `aa` for what you need them, you never use them again a good name will maybe answer this question. If you use better-describing names, it's easier for us to understand your code.

Comment: yes, you're right, I'm editing the question

Comment: Thank you, now it's easier to understand your code and we can better help you.

Comment: To your question, you write `time = Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();` so `time` will always be around 0.016 seconds by 60 FPS and never will go further. You must write `time += Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();` or `time += delta;` because you already have the delta time in this function as parameter.

Comment: Thank you! Sorry for the trouble

Comment: No problem, I only try to help you :)

Comment: Ah, it didnt work :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182779/discussion-between-morchul-and-isadoravr).